# How do you remove items from several list boxes by removing one item associated with them all?

Tags: c#, listbox

[image]

I want to remove Server1 from it's listbox, i'd want it to remove all the other items in the other listboxes associated with it as well. ("Server-Domain1" and all the "Server1-Domain1-CSR's"). Is there a way to do this?

To "bind" these list boxes i just used:

```
domainListBox.Items.Add((serverListBox.SelectedItem) + "-" + (this.domainTextbox.Text));
```

and

```
        csrListBox.Items.Add((domainListBox.SelectedItem) + ("-CSR-1"));
        csrListBox.Items.Add((domainListBox.SelectedItem) + ("-CSR-2"));
        csrListBox.Items.Add((domainListBox.SelectedItem) + ("-CSR-3"));
```

Comment: Yes. Show us what have you tried, and how are you binding those lisboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose your server from servers listbox, you can remove associated items like this (lets pretend there is some remove button, you selecting domain from listbox and clicking on remove button):

```
private void removeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> items = csrListBox.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
        foreach (string item in csrListBox.Items)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^" + domainListBox.SelectedItem + @"\w*");
            Match match = regex.Match(item);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                items.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        csrListBox.DataSource = items;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll give this a try.

Comment: This sort of works, it works when i want to remove anything assosiated with the domain, but when i try it with the server it just removes everything

Comment: Update: I got it working, nothing wrong with your code it was just implementing it properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that encapsulates the `Server` and it's details such as `Domains` and `Csrs`. Create a list of `Servers` and bind it to the first List Box. Then bind the other two List Boxes to the currently selected item of the first List Box. The end result may look like this:

```
serverListBox.ItemSource = Servers;
domainListBox.ItemSource = (serverListBox.SelectedItem as Server).Domains;
csrListBox.ItemSource = (serverListBox.SelectedItem as Server).Csrs;
```

This enables you to set the different List Boxes data without writing a lot of code that could make it unmaintainable.

Comment: I'll give this a try.

Comment: +1 Thats the way to go. My answer just explain how to do it without changing the rest of the code, but obviously yours is good code :)

Comment: Do i need to add any additional namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing your code, you just have to do something like this when you remove your server:

```
        string server = serverListBox.SelectedItem as string;
        serverListBox.Remove(server);
        for (int i = domainListBox.Items.Count -1; i >-1; i--)
        {
            if (domainListBox.Items[i].ToString().StartsWith(server))
            {
                string domain = domainListBox.Items[i].ToString();
                domainListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                for (int j = csrListBox.Items.Count-1; j > -1; j--)
                {
                    if (csrListBox.Items[j].ToString().StartsWith(domain))
                    {
                        csrListBox.Items.RemoveAt(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Edit** I have tested it now, this should work

Comment: i'll give this a try too.

Comment: i'm getting a red line under "Remove"

Answer (score 0):

a better option would be using observable pattern as

```
 public class ObservableObject<T> : IList, IListSource
{

    protected BindingSource src = null;
    List<ListControl> Subscribers;
    ObservableCollection<T> Data = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Data.Count;
        }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsListCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Data[index];
        }

        set
        {
            Data[index] = (T)value;
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Data[index];
        }

        set
        {
            Data[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableObject()
    {
        Data.CollectionChanged += Domains_CollectionChanged;
        Subscribers = new List<ListControl>();
        src = new BindingSource();
        src.DataSource = Data;


    }
    private void Domains_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         src.ResetBindings(false);
    }
    public virtual void Subscribe(ListBox ctrl)
    {

        this.Subscribers.Add(ctrl);
        //ctrl.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", src, "Name",
        //                    true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never));
        ctrl.DataSource = src;
    }

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        Data.Add((T)value);
        return Data.Count - 1;
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        return Data.Contains((T)value);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Data.Clear();
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return Data.IndexOf((T)value);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        Data.Insert(index, (T)value);
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        Data.Remove((T)value);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        Data.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Data.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IList GetList()
    {
        return Data;
    }
}

public class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            this._name = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CSR : BaseModel
{

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }


}
public class Domain : BaseModel
{
    public ObservableObject<CSR> CSRs { get; set; }


    public Domain()
    {
        CSRs = new ObservableObject<CSR>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

}
public class Server : BaseModel
{

    public ObservableObject<Domain> Domains { get; set; }

    public Server()
    {
        Domains = new ObservableObject<Domain>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }


}
public class DataModel : BaseModel
{
    public ObservableObject<Server> Servers
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public DataModel()
    {
        Servers = new ObservableObject<Server>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }


}
```

on Form

```
     DataModel m = new DataModel();
    public Form1()
    {
       ...
        m.Servers.Subscribe(listBox1);
    }
 private void listBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox2.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            m.Servers[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Domains[listBox2.SelectedIndex].CSRs.Subscribe(listBox3);

        }
    }

    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            m.Servers[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Domains.Subscribe(listBox2);

        }
    }
```

you dont have to write code to remove items from forms in this perspective.removing object from model would do